# HTTP PUT request returning a 400 bad request in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-toolkit, strapi

I'm trying to make a react crud app using strapi as the REST API, get, delete, and create are working fine but when i make a PUT request, i get a 400 bad request. am using, redux toolkit and useContext to manage state. take a look, I have created the usePetContext and the store. and am new to react

the PUT page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
// mui components
import {
    Typography,
    TextField,
    Box,
    Button,
    Paper
} from '@mui/material';

// mui icons
import { Edit } from '@mui/icons-material';

// custom components
import BottomNav from './BottomNav';

import { useUpdatePetMutation } from '../services/petApi';
import Loader from './Loader';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { usePetContext } from '../petContext';

export default function EditPetEntry() {
    // input data
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [animal, setAnimal] = useState("");
    const [breed, setBreed] = useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState("");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
    const [sex, setSex] = useState("");
    const {id} = useParams();
    const { petId } = usePetContext();
    // edit req
    const [updatePet, { isLoading }] = useUpdatePetMutation();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "data": {
            "name": name,
            "animal": animal,
            "breed": breed,
            "age": age,
            "location": location,
            "sex": sex
        }
    });
    const handleEditPet = () => {
        updatePet(petId, data);
    };

    console.log(typeof petId);

    return (
        <Box
            component="form"
            sx={{
                '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '50ch' },
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column'
            }}
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
        >
            <div>
                <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom component="div">
                    Edit Pet entry
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-name"
                    label="Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-animal"
                    label="Animal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    helperText="Cat, Dog, Bird"
                    onChange={(e)=>setAnimal(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-breed-input"
                    label="Breed"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e)=>setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-location-input"
                    label="Location"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e)=>setLocation(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-age"
                    label="Age"
                    type="number"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e)=>setAge(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="sex"
                    label="Sex"
                    helperText="Male, Female"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e)=>setSex(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleEditPet} startIcon={<Edit />}>
                    Edit Pet Entry
                </Button>
                {isLoading && <Loader />}
            </div>
            <Paper sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} elevation={3}>
                <BottomNav/>
            </Paper>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

app.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import BottomNav from '../src/components/BottomNav';
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import PetList from '../src/components/PetList';
import CreatePetEntry from '../src/components/CreatePetEntry';
import EditPetEntry from '../src/components/EditPetEntry';
import PetListItem from './components/PetListItem';


function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Pet Adoption</h1>
      <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={ <PetList /> } />
            <Route exact path="/addpet" element={ <CreatePetEntry /> } />
            <Route exact path="/editpet/:id" element={ <EditPetEntry /> } />
          </Routes>
      </div>
      <BottomNav />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

petApi.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const petApiHeaders = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
};

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:1337/api/';

const createRequest = (url) => ({ url, headers: petApiHeaders });

export const petApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'petApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl }),
  tagTypes: ['Pet'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPets: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest('pets'),
      providesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
    addNewPet: builder.mutation({
      query: (payload) => ({
        url: 'pets',
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
    updatePet: builder.mutation({
      query: (id, payload) => ({
        url: `/pets/${id}`,
        method: 'PUT',
        body: payload,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
    deletePet: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `pets/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
  })
})

export const {
    useGetPetsQuery,
    useAddNewPetMutation,
    useUpdatePetMutation,
    useDeletePetMutation,
  } = petApi;
```

petContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const PetContext = createContext();

export const usePetContext = () => {
    return useContext(PetContext);
};

export const PetProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [petId, setPetId] = useState('');

    // get pet id value
    const getPetId = (id) => {
        setPetId(id);
    };

    const value = {
        getPetId,
        petId
    };

    // context provider
    return(
        <PetContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </PetContext.Provider>
    )
};
```

your assistance will be appreciated, If you need more information to diagnose the problem please reach out, I am recreating [this](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-build-a-crud-app-with-react-and-a-headless-cms) tutorial using reactrouter 6 and redux toolkit

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to know for sure what is wrong in your particular case. However, there are generic steps that will make it easier to debug the issue

1. You can check what is the actual request / response in Google Chrome DevTools https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ this is a full docs guide. However, you can see relevant information just by clicking on the row with the error (PUT request in your case). Where you will see what was the data you sent and most likely there is something missing there. This might be a good start. Maybe ID is not populated for some reason, maybe something is not right with payload, etc.? This will help you debug it further.
2. You can also get similar information from the server logs. It is helpful to check what do you receive on the server. Not sure if this is local server in your case or prod one.

Comment: its a rest api like json server(strapi). thanks again, will you mind forking the github project to check it out, need some help and explanation

Comment: I don't see github link attached anywhere

Comment: Sorry was just asking. [github link](https://github.com/Keyzcharly/petpound)

Comment: I will not be able to use as I don't have strapi keys. However, I think you should start by analysing request and response in google chrome and this will most likely explain what is wrong with the request. Feel free to attach screen shot if you need extra pair of eyes

Comment: clone the repo and npm install. i checked the chrome dev tool. [this is the respose](https://imgur.com/PTI3vT9). i still have no clue to what it means

Comment: I haven't applied any keys

Comment: You need to check "payload" tab to see what data you are sending

Comment: [the payload tab](https://imgur.com/a/FmqmpTe), and this is the [headers tab](https://imgur.com/a/UaYbL3R) now i get a 405 method not allowed response